# Web based Image editing and annotation controls for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, image-manipulation

I am for a control that we can buy to crop and annotate images from an ASP.NET web site.

The customer wants to be able to crop, change contrast, etc. AND add shapes (lines, squares, circles, text, etc.)  The image quality doesn't need to be all that high.

The images are used for "evidence" and are annotated to explain what is going on, point to areas of interest, etc.

The customer would perfer web based controls because user will be using a thin client with IE 7.

The customer likes [Phixr](http://www.phixr.com) and [Snipshot](http://snipshot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft

We have webcontrols that can do that.  See DotImage

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage

You can see a demo, download an eval or watch videos tutorials for how to build websites with our controls.  It's 100% AJAX -- supported in IE, FireFox, Safari and Chrome.